# returning user input as history with a list

Tags: c

I'm working on a small program that will get the user input and then stores that input into a linked list and then finally prints the history of what that user has entered.

So if a user enters the string "hello world" then the program will show

```
1 hello world
```

but if the user presses 1 to enter another string "hi everyone" then result should show

```
1 hello world
2 hi everyone
```

but my program isn't working correctly, it shows this instead

```
1 hello world
2 hello world
```

i think it has to do with fgets because when I manually enter the strings with history i get the correct result

It basically will just repeat the last string the user entered. please help!

my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int string_length(char* str){
  int length = 0;
  int i = 0;
  for(i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++){
    length += 1;
  }
  return length;
}

typedef struct s_Item {
  int id;
  char* str;
  struct s_Item* next;
} Item;

typedef struct s_List {
  struct s_Item* root;
} List;

List* init_history(){
    List *list = NULL;
    list = malloc(sizeof(List));
    return list;
}

void add_history(List *list, char *str){
  Item *newItem = (Item*)malloc(sizeof(Item*) * 500);
  newItem->str = str;

  if (list->root == NULL){
    newItem->id = 1;
    list->root = newItem;
  }
  else{
    Item *history = list->root;
    newItem->id = 1;

    while (history->next != NULL){
      newItem->id += 1;
      history = history->next;
    }
    history->next = newItem;
    newItem->id += 1;
  }
}

char *get_history(List *list, int id){
    Item *node = list -> root;
    char *info = "";


    while(node!= NULL){
        if(node->id ==id){
            info= node->str;
            return info;
        }
    node = node->next;
    }

    return info;
}


void print_history(List* list){
  Item* p = list->root;
  printf("History: \n");
  while(p){
    if(p->str)
      printf("%d %s \n", p->id, p->str);
    p = p->next;
  }
}

int main(){   
    char s[100];

    char c = '0';
    List *historyList = init_history();
    while(1){

    printf("type 1 to save string to history, 2 to view history or 3 to quit: \n");
    fgets(s, 100, stdin);

    size_t ln = string_length(s)-1;
        if (s[ln] == '\n')
        s[ln] = '\0';

    c = *s;

    if(c == '3'){
        printf("program terminating...\n");
        break;

    }
    else if(c == '2'){
        printf("Printing History...\n");
        print_history(historyList);
    }
   else{
      printf("Enter string: ");
        char buffer[50];
        fgets(buffer, 50, stdin);
        printf("BUFFER:  %s\n", buffer);

        //add history
        add_history(historyList, buffer);
        print_history(historyList);
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

fgets fills the same buffer each time, so  you are storing in your list multiple copies of the same item.  the buffer in main. (Consider `strdup`?)

Also your malloc is over generous.  You need to  malloc the size of a list (not a pointer).

```
Item *newItem = (Item*)malloc(sizeof(Item) );
```

At some point freeing an item in the list will be needed, where you free the string and the pointer to the Item memory.